# Find magnetic field of parabaloid-spiral particle path

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, charge

Given the components of the particle's path (tcos(at), tsin(at), R(x^2 + y^2)), where a and R are constants, how can I find the magnetic force causing this?

I would like to understand if this can be done with a constant electric field and changing magnetic field and how this can be solved. Is there a way to solve for both B and E?

### [image: edit: added image]

My attempt would be to take the Lorentz Force equation as a differential and remove E from the equation. From what I understand, the path of the point charge is determined by the velocity-cross-magnetic field *only* (not sure), so just finding B without E might suffice. Is this accurate, and can it lead to a solution for E?

Answer (score 2):

Great Question!

First of all, you can solve this problem for the Magnetic Field and the Electromagnetic Field. You won't have to do any work with the Lorentz Force Equation. Instead you will use the solutions to Maxwell's Equations.

$$\pmb{\mathcal{E}}=-\nabla \phi-\frac{\partial{\pmb{A}}}{\partial{t}}$$
$$\pmb{\mathcal{B}}=\nabla \times\pmb{A}$$

where $\phi$ is the scalar potential, $\pmb{A}$ is the vector potential,$\nabla$ is the del vector operator. There are many ways to calculate these potentials, but the formulas that I will use are called the Liénard–Wiechert potentials. The Liénard-Wiechert potentials calculate $\phi$ and $\pmb{A}$ of a point charge moving with arbitrary velocity. The potentials are:

$$\phi (\pmb{r},t)=\frac{q}{4 \pi  \epsilon_0  (1-\pmb{n}\cdot
  \pmb{ \beta_s} ) \left\| \pmb{r}-\pmb{r_s}\right\| } $$
$$A(\pmb{r},t)=\frac{\pmb{\beta _s} \phi (\pmb{r},t)}{c}$$
where
$\pmb{\beta _s}=\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial{\pmb{r_s}}}{\partial{t_s}}$
$\pmb{n}=\frac{r-r_s}{\left\| r-r_s\right\| }$
$t_s=t-\frac{\left\| r-r_s\right\|
   }{c}$
$\pmb{r_s}$ is the position of the point charge in retarded time as experienced by the point charge (due to relativity),$t_s$ is retarded time, $\pmb{r}$ is any point in space, $t$ is time as experience by an observer at $\pmb{r}$, $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of a vacuum, $c$ is the speed of light, and $q$ is the charge of the point charge. Now that we have our equations we can start to solve. The vector that describes the movement of the point charge is 
$$\pmb{r_s}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 t_s \cos (a t_s) \\
 t_s \sin (a t_s) \\
 R \left(t_s^2 \cos ^2(a t_s)+t_s^2 \sin ^2(a
   t_s)\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
So,
$$\pmb{\beta _s}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\cos \left(a t_s\right)-a \sin \left(a
   t_s\right) t_s}{c} \\
 \frac{\sin \left(a t_s\right)+a \cos \left(a
   t_s\right) t_s}{c} \\
 \frac{R \left(2 t_s \cos ^2\left(a t_s\right)+2
   \sin ^2\left(a t_s\right) t_s\right)}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\pmb{n}=\left\{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\left(z-R \left(t_s^2 \sin
   ^2\left(a t_s\right)+t_s^2 \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a
   t_s\right)\right){}^2}}-\frac{t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)}{\sqrt{\left(z-R
   \left(t_s^2 \sin ^2\left(a t_s\right)+t_s^2
   \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a
   t_s\right)\right){}^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{\left(
   z-R \left(t_s^2 \sin ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)+t_s^2 \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a
   t_s\right)\right){}^2}}-\frac{t_s \sin
   \left(a t_s\right)}{\sqrt{\left(z-R
   \left(t_s^2 \sin ^2\left(a t_s\right)+t_s^2
   \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2}},-\frac{R
   t_s^2 \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)}{\sqrt{\left(z-R \left(t_s^2 \sin
   ^2\left(a t_s\right)+t_s^2 \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2}}-\frac{R
   t_s^2 \sin ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)}{\sqrt{\left(z-R \left(t_s^2 \sin
   ^2\left(a t_s\right)+t_s^2 \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a
   t_s\right)\right){}^2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{\left(
   z-R \left(t_s^2 \sin ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)+t_s^2 \cos ^2\left(a
   t_s\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x-t_s \cos
   \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2+\left(y-t_s
   \sin \left(a t_s\right)\right){}^2}}\right\}$$
(Sorry this vector looks like a list) Then, we can get our potentials, but I can't put the potentials into this answer because when I entered the potentials into the box, it said I exceeded 30,000 characters. This also means I can't put the solutions, but I can put some images of the resulting fields!

[image]
A Stream plot of the Electric Field section where y=0. The black dot is the point charge.

[image]
Same graphics, but this animation depicts the Magnetic Field.

I hope this helped!

Comment: Also something interesting to note is how the field changes with the movement of the point charge. Since the solution is relativistic, the field changes over time express how fields change relative to the observer over time.

Comment: +1 ... If you did this in Mathematica ... could you post the code?

Comment: I would be happy to post the code! Would you like the code just for the animation, or would you like the code for the entire process?  @Young

Comment: Here's the mathematica notebook: [here!](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2cgqlai_gblYzNpcmphVlhLSFU)

Comment: @Young I posted the code put forgot to tag you

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you! There is a catch though- the thesis of my work is to relate the path of a nanoscale self replicating crack to that of a charged particle. I want to find the interaction between the electric and magnetic forces (which will represent the tensile and delamination forces of the crack). With that said- is it possible to do this using the Lorentz Force equation? The hypothesis of my work is that an analogy can be constructed using the Lorentz Force equation not Maxwell's Equations. (Tensile, Delamination -> Electric, Magnetic)

Comment: This is a very interesting piece of work because you're connecting Electrodynamics to Continuum Mechanics. Self replicating cracks (especially on the nano layer) are very complicated, and I am not familiar with them myself. But you could calculate the force vector on the continuum in which the crack occurs with the Lorentz Force Equations. Here's the equation I would use on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Continuous_charge_distribution. Then using the force you could calculate the stress tensor and eventually derive the path of the crack. Good Luck!